# How to get selenium script to use a list for values?

Tags: javascript, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to create a selenium script to log into a site with a username and password complete a task, log out then start over but with a multiple different username/passwords. Is it possible to get the script to use values from a text file or something?

```js
<title>New Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" border="1">
<thead>
<tr><td rowspan="1" colspan="3">New Test</td></tr>
</thead><tbody>
<tr>
 <td>open</td>
 <td>/common/oauth2/authorize?client_id/td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>assertTitle</td>
 <td>Sign in to your account</td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>type</td>
 <td>id=cred_userid_inputtext</td>
 <td>example@example.com</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>click</td>
 <td>id=cred_password_inputtext</td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>type</td>
 <td>id=cred_password_inputtext</td>
 <td>password1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>clickAndWait</td>
 <td>id=cred_sign_in_button</td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>click</td>
 <td>css=span.ms-Icon--outlook</td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>select</td>
 <td>id=selTz</td>
 <td>label=‎(UTC-08:00)‎ Pacific Time ‎(US &amp; Canada)‎</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>clickAndWait</td>
 <td>css=span.signinTxt</td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>click</td>
 <td>xpath=(//button[@type='button'])[12]</td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>clickAndWait</td>
 <td>xpath=(//button[@type='button'])[51]</td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>click</td>
 <td>//table[@id='use_another_account']/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/div</td>
 <td></td>
</tr>

</tbody></table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This looks like, I don't know....suspicious ?

Answer (score 0):

Sure it is possible to read from an external source and run your automation test.
If you have a lot of credentials, I would recommend that you directly talk to the test database to retreive that data and then use it for your automation test. I don't know javascript or python but I'm sure that if you Google, you can find a solution on how to do this.

If this is too complex, then you might just prefer to read from a file like a .csv. Python or javascript will probably have some frameworks that you can use to read .csv files. Worst case scenario is you will have to write your own logic to read the file, which I'm sure already exists on the web.

Whatever method you choose, just use your code to read that entity, store the values in variables, and then apply those variables in your tests. Here is a sample of my test using C#. It runs through many 'accessionNumbers' that it reads from an external source.

```
        [Test, TestCaseSource("GetDataList")]
    [Property("PBI#", "35656")]
    public void GivenPopupItemIsOpen_WhenTogglingPopup_ThenPopupOpensAndCloses(string accessionNumber)
    {
        var studentAssesmentPage = OpenAdminResetPageAndGoToBookletLocation(accessionNumber);
        studentAssesmentPage.ShortTextPopup.OpenPopUp();
        studentAssesmentPage.ShortTextPopup.ClosePopUp();
        Assert.IsFalse(studentAssesmentPage.ShortTextPopup.IsPopUpOpen(), "The pop up did not close after trying to close the pop up");
    }
```